# Method call using Inheritance

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I have created a very simple program to test which method will be called when that method will be called through inheritance. 
`Class boo extends foo`.

Using `boo` object, a method from `foo` class `showMe` is called. `showMe` method in `foo` class calls a method `showText` to show the text on the screen.

`boo` class overrides the `showText` method and show a different text.

My prediction was that the method in `foo` class will be called instead of its overridden version in `boo` class. I was wrong and the method in `boo` class was called. Can someone please explain me how that happened. Also, I want to know how to call the method in the `foo` class even if I have a overridden method in `boo` class.

boo class

```
    public class boo extends foo
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            boo main = new boo();

            main.showMe();
        }

        @Override
        public void showText()
        {
            System.out.println("Bruhhh!!!");
        }
}
```

foo class

```
public class foo
{
    protected void showMe()
    {
        showText();
    }

    public void showText()
    {
        System.out.println("Bruhhh Part 2!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code snippet that shows the behavior you are describing (:

Comment: The program runs fine, but the only problem is the showText method from boo class is called. I want to call showText method from foo class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in boo was called because `main` is of type `boo`.

If you want it to print the one in `foo`, you should change `boo main = new boo();` to `foo main = new foo();`

Inheritance is a tree. It's easier to understand if you try to relate it to real life trees, like evolution, vehicles, professions and related branches. For example, there are many types of engineers. At first there were `Engineer`, then `ElectricalEngineer`, then `ComputerEngineer`.

```
public class Engineer {
    public void do() {
        System.out.println("I build stuff");
    }
}

public class ElectricalEngineer {
    public void do() {
        System.out.println("I build electronics");
    }
}

public class ComputerEngineer {
    public void do() {
        System.out.println("I build computers");
    }
}

Engineer eng = new Engineer();
ElectricalEngineer ee = new ElectricalEngineer();
ComputerEngineer ce = new ComputerEngineer();

eng.do(); // prints "I build stuff"
ee.do(); // prints "I build electronics"
ce.do(); // prints "I build computers"

// eng is of type Engineer
// ee is of type ElectricalEngineer
// ce is of type ComputerEngineer

Engineer ee2 = new ElectricalEngineer();
Engineer ce2 = new ComputerEngineer();

ee2.do(); // prints "I build electronics"
ce2.do(); // prints "I build computers"
```

Here, it looks like `ee2` is of type `Engineer`, but it actually is `ElectricalEngineer`. It will call its overridden `do()` method. Same with `ce2`

```
ElectricalEngineer ce3 = new ComputerEngineer();

ce3.do(); // prints "I build computers"
```

But if you do:

```
ElectricalEngineer ee3 = new Engineer();
ComputerEngineer ce4 = new ElectricalEngineer();
ComputerEngineer ce5 = new Engineer();
```

You'll get errors on all of them because an `ElectricalEngineer` IS an Engineer. A `ComputerEngineer` IS an `ElectricalEngineer`. `ComputerEngineer` IS an `Engineer` as well. But not all `Engineers` are guaranteed to be `ComputerEngineer` or `ElectricalEngineer`. They may be `CivilEngineer` for all you know.

Answer (score 1):

Except from Alex's answer, if you still want to call foo's method from boo while instantiating only boo, you will have to create another method in `boo`. So your boo class becomes:

```
public class boo extends foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boo main = new boo();

        main.showMe();
    }

    @Override
    public void showText()
    {
        System.out.println("Bruhhh!!!");
    }

    public void showFooText(){
        super.showText();
    }
}
```

calling `showFooText()` will display text from foo.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question what exactly you're looking for, but I think this covers most of your cases:

```
public class boo extends foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Create & use a "foo" object
        System.out.println("Use foo's showText()");
        foo main1 = new foo();
        main1.showMe();

        System.out.println("=====================");

        //Create & use a "boo" object (but pass it around as a "foo")
        System.out.println("Use boo's showText()");
        foo main2 = new boo();
        main2.showMe();

        System.out.println("=====================");

        //Create & use a "boo" object
        System.out.println("Use boo's showText()");
        boo main3 = new boo();
        main3.showMe();
    }

    @Override
    public void showText()
    {
        System.out.println("Bruhhh!!!");
        super.showText();
    }
}
```

The version of `showText` that gets called is dependent on the type of `main`.  If you look at the three examples in the code above, the `new` statement that creates the object controls what `showText` will get called.  It doesn't matter if you pass the object around as a `foo` or `boo`; polymorphism will ensure that the `showText` on the actual type of the object you created will be called.

To answer your other question, you can user the `super.method()` syntax to call a parent class method from a child class.

Answer (score 1):

Method calls are resolved using the runtime class of the `this` object, not the compile time type of the `this` reference.

Therefore, when `showMe()` invokes `showText()`, the runtime determines the runtime class of the `this` object, which is `boo`, and looks for the method in that class.

The only way to invoke an overridden method is using `super` in a subclass. For instance, you could do:

```
class boo extends foo {
    @Override 
    public void showMe() {
        super.showText();
    }
```

to have the `showMe()` method invoke the overridden super implementation.

Answer (score 1):

if

```
//SuperClass
class A()
{
    public void methodExample()
    {
        //Origional Functionality
    }
}

//SubClass
class B extends A()
{
    @Override
    public void methodExample()
    {
        //New Functionality
    }
}
```

To my knowledge, class 'B' cannot expect the origional (or more general, not-overridden) functionality from any in its superclass 'A' if 'B' has overridden that method with a new functionality. If you still need that functionality, you may want to make a method in the superclass which you do not overrun.

Answer (score 1):

```
Boo list = new Boo();
list.showText();

Foo list2 = new Boo();
list2.showText();

Foo list3 = new Foo();
list3.showText();

// Boo list4 = new Foo(); Incorrect!!
```

result

```
Bruhhh!!!
Bruhhh!!!
Bruhhh Part 2!!!
```

By the way, In Java Class name must start with ***Uppercase***!!

So, How does it work? : Understand the Object and Instance in Java

**In first code**

```
Boo list = new Boo();
list.showText();
```

Actually, list.showText() method is called in `Boo` class (All methods & data of `Boo` class is instanced in Memory) 
1) If there is `@override showText()`, then it will be called in `Boo` Class
2) If there isn't, then it will be called in parent Object

**In Second code**

```
Foo list2 = new Boo();
list2.showText();
```

Actually, list.showText() method is called in `Boo` class but used `Foo` Object

 (What? it means that `Boo` class **must extend** `Foo` Class to use Foo Object!! and list2 can only call methods in `Foo` Class)

1) If there is `@override showText()` in `Boo`, then it will be called in `Boo` Class
2) If there isn't, then it will be called in parent Object